# TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got int

Tags: python, qt, integer, int, squish

I'm using Squish 6.4.2 to test my Qt applications, using Python 2.7.10 as the test scripting language and got the following error message when trying to use the `range()` function:

`TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got int.`

Here's a small code example and my output in Squish:

```
def main():
    test.log(str(range(4)))
    test.log(str(range(int(4))))
```

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
Error: Script Error
    Detail: TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got int.
```

As you can see `range(4)` works but `range(int(4))` doesn't.

I've tried running the same code in the Python console of the Python version that is shipped with the Squish application, and there both `range()` calls work.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> range(4)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> range(int(4))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Also when I compare integers to a casted int the comparison result is wrong in Squish. For example in Squish:

```
def main():
    test.log(str(7<4))
    test.log(str(7 < int(4)))
```

gives

```
False
True
```

In the Python console the result is correct though.

Comment: Works fine for me. Which is your version of Python? `import sys; print (sys.version)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Squish int is different from the Python int:

> Squish's int represents the Squish type for an integer in the
>   wrapper's C and C++ code.
>
> Like the other hidden symbols, to access Python's int() function one
>   can use it from the package __builtin__ (Python 2) or builtins (Python
>   3).

(Other types are different as well)

See [Squish's int vs. Python's int](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-py.html#squish.int)

Or more generally [Python Notes](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-py.html#rgs-py) in the Squish manual.

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much! I used the `restore_python_bool_int_long()` function from the docs and I now I can use the Python types again. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)